# How to keep YARN application logs in the local file system instead of HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, elastic-stack, amazon-emr

I have `yarn.log-aggregation-enable` set to `true` that is making `NodeManager` to immediately concatenate all of the containers logs into one file and upload them into `HDFS` in `${yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir}/${user.name}/logs/<application ID>` and delete them from the local user logs directory.

I would like to keep these logs in the local file system (*not* `HDFS`) for a while so that I can forward these logs to the persistent logging mechanism like ELK.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount `hdfs` to local filesystem by following below steps:

```
sudo yum install hadoop-hdfs-fuse -y
sudo mkdir -p /data/hdfs/

mount_hdfs_locally() {

  sudo hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://$(resource-manager-hostname):8020 /data/hdfs/

  echo "HDFS location is mounted locally"
}

mount_hdfs_locally
```

And now you have access to the yarn logs locally.